# Write stored procedure with dynamic SQL

Tags: amazon-redshift, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I want to write a stored procedure that takes a textparameter (table_name) and that  executes a query based on that tablename: select count(*) from  and that writes the value found to a table.

It is the `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM VARTABLE_NAME)` part that I do not know how to implement in Amazon Redshift

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  PROCEDURE SP_LOGGING (VARSTART INT, VARRUNID INT , VARPHASE VARCHAR, VARTABLE_NAME VARCHAR)
AS $$

BEGIN
            IF VARSTART = 1 THEN
                BEGIN
                UPDATE AUDIT.RUN_TEST
                SET TABLE_NAME = VARTABLE_NAME
                ,"no_of_records_at_start" = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM VARTABLE_NAME)
                END;

            ELSEIF VARSTART = 0 THEN    
                BEGIN
                UPDATE AUDIT.RUN_TEST
                SET TABLE_NAME = VARTABLE_NAME
                ,"no_of_records_at_end" = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM VARTABLE_NAME)
                END;
            END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `EXECUTE` to run dynamic SQL.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_logging (
      varstart      INT
    , varrunid      INT 
    , varphase      VARCHAR
    , vartable_name VARCHAR ) 
AS $$
BEGIN
    IF varstart = 1 THEN
        EXECUTE 'UPDATE audit.run_test
                    SET table_name = '||vartable_name||'
                      , start_rows = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '||vartable_name||' )';
    ELSEIF varstart = 0 THEN    
        EXECUTE 'UPDATE audit.run_test
                    SET table_name = '||vartable_name||'
                      , end_rows = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '||vartable_name||')';
    ELSE 
        RAISE ERROR 'Value of `varstart` must be 1 or 0. Received `%`.',varstart;
    END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Comment: Small change : ,TABLE_NAME = '''||VARTABLE_NAME||'''
Otherwise genius idea to wrap the whole query in dynamic sql en not just the select part!